# Tkinter throws weird incomplete exception

Tags: python, exception, tkinter

I'm creating an app that's supposed to pilot a robot I made and should be able to ask the robot to take a picture and get it back using SCP.

```
def snap(self): #method of the netCamera class that asks the robot to take a picture
    if(subprocess.run(["ssh", self.host, "python3", "~/PilotAppTemp/scripts/snap.py"]).returncode):
        print("ERROR: Unable to take picture")
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def getImage(self): #method of the netCamera class that gets the picture
    self.imageCount += 1
    print("a")
    command = "scp " + self.host + ":" + self.robotPath + "/img.png " + self.localPath + "/img" + self.imageCount + ".png" #problem
    print("command : " + command)
    if(subprocess.run(command).returncode):
        print("ERROR")
        return 0
    else:
        return self.imageCount

def camera(self, event): #method of the App class (controler) used as callback for when the user clicks on the button to take a picture, that uses the aformentionned methods to get an image from the robot and then display it
        if(self.robotCam.snap()):
            self.history.log("Error: unable to take picture")
        else:
            imageNum = self.robotCam.getImage()
            if(imageNum == 0):
                self.history.log("Error: unable to take picture")
            else:
                self.image("img" + imageNum + ".png")
```

Within my getImage() method however I get an exception with a weird message

```
a
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anthony.JACCARD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py",rgs)
ge()
problem

te str (not "int") to str
```

As you can see, it's full of uncomplete lines. I've used the infamous print() debugging method and could determine that the problem comes from the line with the "#problem" comment (you can see that "a" is printed but "command: ..." is not). Now that my code fails at a subprocess call I could understand but I cannot figure out why a simple concatenation gives me such a strange exception.

Does anyone have an idea as to how to fix this ?

Comment: It seems you are concatenating both `int` and `str` on your variable `command`. Try use string formatting instead and see if you got the same error.

Comment: I've converted ImageCount to a string (```str(self.imageCount)```) but I still get the same mistake

Comment: And what about the other variables? Are you 100% certain they are also strings?

Comment: I've tried doing it that way ( ```command = "scp %s:%s/img.png %s/img%d.png" % (self.host, self.robotPath, self.localPath, self.imageCount)``` ) and it seems to work so it was indeed a type problem. Thanks

Comment: If you are not stuck to an older version of Python, i suggest you take a look at [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). It is much easier to read in terms of string formatting.